# Windows Phone Back-key press event?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am working on a windows phone application.

I noticed that after I select particular item in listbox on Page-A and navigate to page-B, on page-B if I press "back" key, the item on page-A in listbox is remain selected.

But I want the page-A Items Refresh or Reload when go to page-A on "back" key press.

I tried to implement the BackKeyPressed event handler of the page but it does not seem worked for me.

Anyone has any good idea with this? thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the `Page.OnNavigatedTo` method for page-A and check its `NavigationEventArgs`-typed `e` parameter's `NavigationMode` field to see if the page is being navigated to using "Back" button.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back)
  {
    this.DoVeryUsefulStuff();
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this its works fine but it's need to press back button twice time to back first screen(page-A)

Answer (score 0):

After handling the selecteditemchanged set the selected index to -1. This will reset the selection. It will also avoid the annoying 'select the same item and nothing happens' behavior.

Comment: In my code i am using MVVM concept. when using  "selected index to -1" it doesnt work.